# Downloading Music from YT

Tags: web-applications, youtube, metadata, mp3, converters

If I copy a video link from my YouTube playlist and the name of the playlist for example is "Music", paste the link for this specific video/song onto a converter site, and then convert it to a mp3 file, will the mp3 file's metadata show the name of the YouTube playlist name which is "Music" that contains the video/song link i want to convert or is that impossible?

Comment: If the MP3 converter accepts an URL such as https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DjmKjINRVwo&list=PL8wZFyWE1ZaLa64coao3W824KDykI9Yy7 or https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL8wZFyWE1ZaLa64coao3W824KDykI9Yy7 then it may includes correctly the playlist metadata but if you provide https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DjmKjINRVwo then it is impossible as there isn't any link between your playlist and the music video.

Comment: @BenjaminLoison thank you for understanding my question!

Comment: So basically what your saying is, the playlist name won't be visible and impossible to see if for example "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DjmKjINRVwo" if the link is like this?

Comment: Correct, as the video may be in multiple playlists and just this link doesn't precise which playlist.